# IOException / Java Security Access Error when saving a file

Tags: java, swing

I've got an debugging problem!
I have written a method that should save an object called "Player" to an .bin file.

Here is the shortest version of my saving method, which includes only the "saving process".

```
    public void saveButton_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ObjectOutputStream playerSave;
        try {
            playerSave = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("save/player_data.bin"));
            playerSave.writeObject(Main.player);
            playerSave.close(); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }   
}
```

Directly after starting this method, i'm getting following errors from the console.

```
java.io.IOException: failed to load image contents
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at MainWindow.saveButton_ActionPerformed(MainWindow.java:143)
at MainWindow$2.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:129)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It looks like `Main.player` has a field with an `ImageIcon` that doesn't have an image.

Comment: @matt Thank you very much! Problem is solved, I had the Image in the wrong directory. Now everything works fine.

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry for the circumstances, my future questions will conclude more information!

Comment: @GhostCat I have edited my question, I hope it's now better. English is not my native language so I have some difficulties in expressing myself and my question. But I'm learning and I thank you for every advice and help :)

Comment: Lets honor your efforts then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you are getting is occurring when you try to Serialize (`ObjectOutputStream.writeObject`) your `Main.player`.

`Main.player` has an ImageIcon field, that does not have an image, so it cannot be serialized.